# MySQL 5.5.19 gets error 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, centos

I have a fresh install of MySQL 5.5.19 on a CentOS 5 server. It is not letting me access anything or log in with phpMyAdmin. Below is the errors from trying different things.

```
$ mysql 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$ mysql -u root -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am able to restart mysqld but my problem is this error is hindering what I can do with MySQL. Thank you for any input.

Comment: Are supplying the correct root password?

Comment: I don't remember setting up a root mysql password. I just installed 5.5.19 and these errors are showing up so I figured I wouldn't even be able to enter a root password. Any advice on that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in specifying the user with `-u root -p`, assuming the root user has a password on it.

The failure would imply that the wrong password is being entered.  If you cannot get the login to work, you are stuck resetting the root password.

Add `skip-grant-tables` to your MySQL configuration and restart the service; this will allow root login with no password.  Once that's done, set the password (`update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('newpass') where User='root';`), verify that there's no craziness happening with the host specifications for root in the user table (and check for anonymous user specifications with a blank username, too; they can be problematic), remove the `skip-grant-tables` option, and restart the service.  You should now be able to log in with your new password.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I add the skip-grant-tables step?

Comment: Add it as a line in your `/etc/my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 2):

If you can access your mysql databases using the root account or you forgot your password, you can use the following [instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) to reset it.